# Passing parameters to foldLeft scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to use Scala's `foldLeft` function to compare a Stream with a List of Lists.

This is a snippet of the code I have

```
def freqParse(pairs: (Pair,Int,String), record: String): (Pair,Int,String) ={

    val m: Pair = ("","")
    val t: FreqPairs = Map((m,0))
    (pairs._1,pairs._2,pairs._3)
}

val freqItems = items.map(v => (v._1)).toList
val cross = freqItems.flatMap(x => freqItems.map(y => (x, y))) // cross product to get pair of frequent items
val freq = lines.foldLeft(pairs,0,delim)(freqParse)
```

`cross` is basically a lists where each element is a pair of strings List(List(a,b), List(a,c)...).

`lines` is an input stream with a record per line (25902 lines in total).

I want to count how many times each pair (or each element in `cross`) occurs in the entirety of the stream. Essentially comparing all elements in `cross` to all elements in lines.

I decided foldLeft because that way I can take each line in the stream and split it at a delimiter and then check if both the elements in `cross` appear or not.

I am able to split each record in `lines` but I don't know how to pass the `cross` variable to the function to begin the comparison.

Comment: WDYM with compare? Why do you think `foldLeft` is a good option?

Comment: cross is basically a lists where each element is a pair of strings List(List(a,b), List(a,c)...) and I wan to count how many times each pair occurs in the entirety of the stream. I decided foldLeft because that way I can take each line in the stream and split it at a delimiter and then check if both the elements in my List of Lists appear or not. It may be the wrong way to look at this problem but I am unsure

Comment: I would recommend you to edit your question to include that last comment with more details, like how the input looks like and what is the expected output.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/XvhWyyfmR7isfKeM3AWdfg/1